# CPython Script Executor does't work on Pentaho Kettle

Tags: python-3.x, pentaho, cpython, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Hellow Guys

First of all, i'm using the windows 10, java_1.8.0_333, and Pentaho 9.3

I'm trying to many ways to run my Python code in Pentaho, but isn't work.

I try reinstall my Python using diferent version, try to change my java version, and try oldest version of Pentaho, but no way works.

If a ran my Python script using the PyCharm, it's works, but if i try to run the same script, or create a new Python script in Pentaho, does't works, and i receive this error.

[image]

Inside CPython is a basic script that declares the variable name and receives the string "Test"

I think this error is about somenthing in my computer, but i don't no why

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to the version of the libraries that I had installed, mainly those related to Pandas and Numpy. I downgraded to pandas version 1.4.4 and made sure I only have one version in both python and anaconda (you can see this with conda list pandas and pip list pandas), uninstall pandas from both versions and try installing version 1.4 .4 of pandas.